# Enable duplicates in Postgis queries to speed up query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a Postgis query that selects all points in given radius from locations.

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(12.1234 12.1234)'), 789) 
OR ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(23.4567 23.4567)'), 789) 
OR ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(34.5678 34.5678)'), 789)
```

When I analyze it with `EXPLAIN` I can see

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=964.16..1051.01 rows=1 width=4)
Recheck Cond: ((location && 'E61A301BC000002OBFUSCATEDDAT05123240'::geography) OR (location && '010020E610OBFUSCATEDDATAC9ACE4E0E3240'::geography) OR (location && '0101000OBFUSCATEDDATA8FC3042080020E613240'::geography) )
Filter: (((location && 'E61A301BC000002OBFUSCATEDDAT05123240'::geography) AND ('010020E610OBFUSCATEDDATAC9ACE4E0E3240'::geography && _st_e...SOMETHING
->  BitmapOr  (cost=964.16..964.16 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on global_points_gix  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=0)
  Index Cond: (location && 'E61A301BC000002OBFUSCATEDDAT05123240'::geography)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on global_points_gix  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=0)
  Index Cond: (location && '010020E610OBFUSCATEDDATAC9ACE4E0E3240'::geography)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on global_points_gix  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=0)
  Index Cond: (location && '0101000020OBFUSCATEDDATA8FC3042080020E613240'::geography)
```

This makes me think that searching for points is very fast but merging result to exclude duplicates is expensive. Am I right? Can I somehow enable duplicates if I'm ok with them? I tried to replace `OR` with `UNION SELECT` but it didn't made it.

Comment: You could try to split your query in 3 subquery, merging the results using UNION ALL

Comment: I think this is valid approach as `ALL` do not check for duplicates. For some reason it didn't helped. The bitmapOR disappeared, but the Index Scan is now more costly `Index Scan using global_points_gix on hyperlocal  (cost=0.41..8.81` and I really have 218 points (not just 3).